# Replication test failed, site Moved Temporarily (Dispatcher Flush Agent)

Tags: caching, single-sign-on, aem

I have a CQ Dispatcher configured behind a SSO(single sign on), so when I access the dispatcher URL it will first redirect me to the SSO login page and then after entering the credentials it moves to the dispatcher(My home page).
There isn't a problem in accessing the dispatcher URL

**Problem Statement**

Problem is with flushing the old content in the cache and getting in the new content onto the cache.

**Editing the flush agent**

Under the transport tab in the URI section when I give in the value  dispatcherURL/dispatcher/invalidate.cache and test the connection it says site moved to the particular sso login page.

**What I did**

1. I tried giving in the SSO credentials under the transport tab with
   URI as dispatcherURL/dispatcher/invalidate.cache
2. I tried giving in the SSO credentials under the transport tab with
   URI as
       SSOURL/dispatcher/invalidate.cache [It is redirected URL]

Please share your knowledge around this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option here is to create a new virtualhost in Apache, available without SSO. It should be configured in such manner that only flush agent (and no external clients) can access it. If Apache is installed on the same host as CQ, the virtualhost can be bound to the localhost interface. Otherwise, it should [only `allow` connections](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#allow) from the CQ5 host.

The virtualhost should include the dispatcher configuration, copied from your regular virtualhost.

If you have virtualhost like this, you can configure the flush agent without need to deal with authorization.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tomek, I'll try this option and will let you know.